# Regex difference between word boundary end and edge

Tags: regex, r, cpu-word, word-boundary

The R help file for [regex](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) says

> The symbols \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the
>   beginning and end of a word. The symbol \b matches the empty string at
>   the edge of a word

What is the difference between an end and an edge (of a word)?

Comment: Did my answer help, or do you need any more clarifications?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the `\b` and `\<` / `\>` is that `\b` can be used in PCRE regex patterns (when you specify `perl=TRUE`) and ICU regex patterns (*stringr* package).

```
> s = "no where nowhere"
> sub("\\<no\\>", "", s)
[1] " where nowhere"
> sub("\\<no\\>", "", s, perl=T) ## \> and \< do not work with PCRE
[1] "no where nowhere"
> sub("\\bno\\b", "", s, perl=T) ## \b works with PCRE
[1] " where nowhere"

> library(stringr)
> str_replace(s, "\\bno\\b", "")
[1] " where nowhere"
> str_replace(s, "\\<no\\>", "")
[1] "no where nowhere"
```

The advantage of `\<` (always stands for the beginning of a word) and `\>` (always matches the end of a word) is that they are unambiguous. The `\b` may match both positions.

One more thing to consider ([refrence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)):

> POSIX 1003.2 mode of gsub and gregexpr does not work correctly with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., `pattern = "\b"`). Use `perl = TRUE` for such matches (but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent).

Comment: Are there further differences?  Does the output of this make sense to you or is this a bug `txt <- c("My name is ASDFNAKFANDpancake"); gsub("\\<", "%", txt)`?

Comment: There is a bug in `gsub` when you use it with a TRE regex, use the PCRE `gsub("\\b", "%", txt, perl=T)`, see my update.

Comment: If you ask me, you'd better stick to `\b`: it is recognized by most if not all regex online testers (like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)). Use zero-width assertion only replacements with caution.

Comment: @Rico: If the answer works for you please consider accepting.