# R: regex with \< or \>

Tags: r, regex

I'm working through *Automated Data Collection with R 3rd Ed* and on page 205 there's an example that is not working.  I am wondering if it's because R has changed or I am doing something wrong:

```
example.obj <- "1. A small sentence. - 2. Another tiny sentence."

unlist(str_extract_all(example.obj, "e\\>"))
```

the book indicates the result should be:

```
[1] "e" "e"
```

but I get:

```
[1] character(0)
```

In the next example, they use 
\b and that seems to work for me:

```
 unlist(str_extract_all(example.obj, "e\\b"))
[1] "e" "e"
```

The book uses the /> and \< a bunch so I want to be able to use them too - they seem like they'd be helpful.  Anyone know what could be happening here?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: See [Regex difference between word boundary end and edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183288/regex-difference-between-word-boundary-end-and-edge/36183563#36183563). You cannot use `\>` and `\<` with stringr regex methods. You need to use `\b`.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew thank you! I am still new at this so searching for existing answers has proven challenging.